# How to compare data in a sqlite column to a const char in c++

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, comparison

I'm trying to compare all column data against a const char to see if the name in the column matches the player name that is connected to the game server. The comparison in the spaghetticode below does not work properly and results in new rows being made even if the player name already exists in the sqlite database. What is the correct way to do this comparison? Thanks in advance for your help.

Here's the snippet with the problematic section:

```
if(enable_sqlite_db) {
            sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
            sqlite3 *db;
            char *zErrMsg = 0;
            int  rc;
            const char *sql;
            bool name_match = false;
            const char* player_database_names;
            char *p_name = ci->name;
            char *p_ip = ci->ip;
            
            rc = sqlite3_open("playerinfo.db", &db);
            if( rc ){
                fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
                exit(0);
            }else{
                if(sql_console_msgs) fprintf(stdout, "Opened database successfully\n");
            }
            if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
                fprintf(stderr, "SQL Database Error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
                sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
            }else{
                defformatstring(sqlstrprep)("SELECT NAME FROM PLAYERINFO");
                rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlstrprep, -1, &stmt, NULL);
        
                
                while ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                    int id = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, SQLITE_ROW);
                    int columns = sqlite3_column_count(stmt);
                    if(sql_console_msgs) out(ECHO_CONSOLE, "-- id: %d row: %d columns: %d", id, SQLITE_ROW, columns);
                    player_database_names = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0));
                }
                if(player_database_names == p_name) name_match = true;
                else if(player_database_names != p_name) name_match = false;
            }
```

Here is the full code:

```
  static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
            printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
    
    bool sql_console_msgs = true;
    void QServ::savestats(clientinfo *ci)
    {
        if(enable_sqlite_db) {
            sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
            sqlite3 *db;
            char *zErrMsg = 0;
            int  rc;
            const char *sql;
            bool name_match = false;
            const char* player_database_names;
            char *p_name = ci->name;
            char *p_ip = ci->ip;
            
            rc = sqlite3_open("playerinfo.db", &db);
            if( rc ){
                fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
                exit(0);
            }else{
                if(sql_console_msgs) fprintf(stdout, "Opened database successfully\n");
            }
            if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
                fprintf(stderr, "SQL Database Error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
                sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
            }else{
                defformatstring(sqlstrprep)("SELECT NAME FROM PLAYERINFO");
                //defformatstring(sqlstrprep)("SELECT group_concat(NAME) FROM PLAYERINFO");
                rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlstrprep, -1, &stmt, NULL);
        
                
                while ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                    //sometimes returns incorrectly - keeps creating undesired new rows firstguy, secondguy, firstguy
                    int id = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, SQLITE_ROW);
                    int columns = sqlite3_column_count(stmt);
                    if(sql_console_msgs) out(ECHO_CONSOLE, "-- id: %d row: %d columns: %d", id, SQLITE_ROW, columns);
                    player_database_names = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0));
                    //if (std::to_string(player_database_names).find(p_name) != std::string::npos) name_match = true;
                    //else name_match = false;
                    if(sql_console_msgs) out(ECHO_CONSOLE, "-- player db names: %s", player_database_names);
                }
                //if(!strcmp(player_database_names, p_name)) name_match = true;
                //else if(strcmp(player_database_names, p_name)) name_match = false;
                if(player_database_names == p_name) name_match = true;
                else if(player_database_names != p_name) name_match = false;
            }
            
            sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PLAYERINFO("    \
            "NAME                       TEXT    NOT NULL,"    \
            "FRAGS                       INT    NOT NULL,"    \
            "DEATHS                      INT    NOT NULL,"    \
            "FLAGS                       INT    NOT NULL,"    \
            "PASSES                      INT    NOT NULL,"    \
            "IP                         TEXT    NOT NULL,"    \
            "ACCURACY          DECIMAL(4, 2)    NOT NULL,"    \
            "KPD               DECIMAL(4, 2)    NOT NULL);";
            rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
            if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
                fprintf(stderr, "SQLITE3 ERROR @ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS: %s\n", zErrMsg);
                sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
            }else{
                if(sql_console_msgs) {
                    if(!name_match) fprintf(stdout, "-- No previous record found under that name\n");
                    else fprintf(stdout, "-- Found name already, updating record instead\n");
                }
            }
            
            char sqlINSERT[500];
            char sqlUPDATE[1000];
            int p_frags = ci->state.frags;
            int p_deaths = ci->state.deaths;
            int p_flags = ci->state.flags;
            int p_passes = ci->state.passes;
            int p_acc = (ci->state.damage*100)/max(ci->state.shotdamage, 1);
            int p_kpd = (ci->state.frags)/max(ci->state.deaths, 1);
            
            //name is different
            if(!name_match) {
                snprintf(sqlINSERT, 500, "INSERT INTO PLAYERINFO( NAME,FRAGS,DEATHS,FLAGS,PASSES,IP,ACCURACY,KPD ) VALUES (\"%s\", %d, %d, %d, %d, \"%s\", %d, %d)",p_name,p_frags,p_deaths,p_flags,p_passes,p_ip,p_acc,p_kpd);
                //sqlEscape(sqlINSERT);
                rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlINSERT, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
            }
            //client name matches db record, update db if new info is > than db info
            else if(name_match)  {
                snprintf(sqlUPDATE, 10000,
                        "UPDATE PLAYERINFO SET FRAGS = %d+(SELECT FRAGS FROM PLAYERINFO) WHERE NAME = \"%s\";"     \
                        "UPDATE PLAYERINFO SET DEATHS = %d+(SELECT DEATHS FROM PLAYERINFO) WHERE NAME = \"%s\";"   \
                        "UPDATE PLAYERINFO SET FLAGS = %d+(SELECT FLAGS FROM PLAYERINFO) WHERE NAME = \"%s\";"     \
                        "UPDATE PLAYERINFO SET PASSES = %d+(SELECT PASSES FROM PLAYERINFO) WHERE NAME = \"%s\";"   \
                        "UPDATE PLAYERINFO SET ACCURACY = %d+(SELECT ACCURACY FROM PLAYERINFO) WHERE NAME = \"%s\";" \
                        "UPDATE PLAYERINFO SET KPD = %d+(SELECT KPD FROM PLAYERINFO) WHERE NAME = \"%s\";",
                        ci->state.frags, ci->name, ci->state.deaths, ci->name, ci->state.flags, ci->name, ci->state.passes, ci->name, p_acc, ci->name, p_kpd, ci->name);
                //sqlEscape(sqlUPDATE);
                rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlUPDATE, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
            }
            if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
                fprintf(stderr, "SQLITE3 ERROR @ INSERT & UPDATE: %s\n", zErrMsg);
                sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
            }else{
                if(sql_console_msgs) fprintf(stdout, "Playerinfo modified\n");
            }
            sqlite3_close(db);
        }
    }
    
    void QServ::getstats(clientinfo *ci)
    {
        if(enable_sqlite_db) {
            sqlite3 *db;
            char *zErrMsg = 0;
            int rc;
            char *sql;
            const char* data = "Callback function called";
            
            rc = sqlite3_open("playerinfo.db", &db);
            if( rc ){
                fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
                exit(0);
            }
            
            if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
                fprintf(stderr, "SQL Database Error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
                sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
            }else{
                sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
                defformatstring(sqlstrprep)("SELECT NAME,FRAGS,ACCURACY,KPD FROM PLAYERINFO WHERE NAME == \"%s\";", ci->name);
                rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlstrprep, -1, &stmt, NULL);
                
                bool necho = false;
                while ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                    const char* name = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0));
                    const char* allfrags = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1));
                    const char* avgacc = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2));
                    const char* avgkpd = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3));
                    if(!necho) {
                        if(avgacc == NULL) out(ECHO_SERV, "Name: \f0%s\f7, Total Frags: \f3%s\f7, Average KPD: \f6%s", name, allfrags, avgkpd);
                        else if(avgkpd == NULL) out(ECHO_SERV, "Name: \f0%s\f7, Total Frags: \f3%s\f7, Average Accuracy: \f2%s%%", name, allfrags, avgacc);
                        else out(ECHO_SERV, "Name: \f0%s\f7, Total Frags: \f3%s\f7, Average Accuracy: \f2%s%%\f7, Average KPD: \f6%s", name,allfrags,avgacc,avgkpd);
                        necho = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            sqlite3_close(db);
        }
    }
    
    void QServ::getnames(clientinfo *ci) {
        if(enable_sqlite_db) {
            sqlite3_stmt *stmt3;
            sqlite3 *db;
            int rc;
            rc = sqlite3_open("playerinfo.db", &db);
            defformatstring(sqlstrprep3)("SELECT group_concat(NAME, \", \") FROM PLAYERINFO WHERE IP == \"%s\";", ci->ip);
            rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlstrprep3, -1, &stmt3, NULL);
            while ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt3)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                std::string names(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt3, 0)));
                defformatstring(nmsg)("Names from IP \f2%s\f7: %s", ci->ip, names.c_str());
                out(ECHO_SERV, nmsg);
            }
            sqlite3_close(db);
        }
    }

    void QServ::disconnectclient(clientinfo *ci)
    {
        if(enable_sqlite_db) savestats(ci);
    }
```

Comment: This looks like idiomatic C code rather than idiomatic C++ code.  The more efficient way to do this operation is to do the logic on the database side rather than doing the logic in the C++ code.

Comment: [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

Comment: @Eljay would you happen to have an example of what database logic I could use?

Comment: Did you copy and paste that code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65226950/how-to-stop-sql-injection-vulnerability)? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Where did you find `defformatstring(sqlstrprep)`? How is this ever going to be useful to you? And more important, you should provide a MINIMAL WORKING EXAMPLE. How can that code be working, when there's no `main()`?

Comment: `SELECT NAME FROM PLAYERINFO` and then `if (name == "Bob") ...` versus `SELECT NAME FROM PLAYERINFO WHERE NAME = 'Bob'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm always amused by the fact that nobody wants to provide a minimal working example. In the end, I created one myself to show how to do this thing:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "sqlite3.h"

int main(void)
{
    int rc;
    sqlite3 *db;
    rc = sqlite3_open("playerinfo.db", &db);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Opened database successfully\n");
    }
    
    char *zErrMsg = NULL;
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, 
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PlayerInfo (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);"
        "REPLACE INTO PlayerInfo(id, name) VALUES (1,'John'),(2,'Paul'),(3,'George'),(4,'Ringo'),(5,'Pete'),(6,'Stuart');",
        NULL, 0, &zErrMsg);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL Database Error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    const char *search_name = "Ringo";
    bool name_match = false;

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    char *zSql = "SELECT name FROM PlayerInfo";
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, zSql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
    while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        const char* player_database_names = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
        
        if (strcmp(player_database_names, search_name) == 0) {
            name_match = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

    printf("Search name: %s - Result: %s\n", search_name, name_match ? "true" : "false");

    sqlite3_close(db);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The original code had **a lot** of very strange things. It clearly looks as if a bunch of stuff was pasted together without reason.

I never used SQLite before, but it's really very well done. So the idea is to

- Open the DB (`sqlite3_open()`) and check if successfull.
- Create and populate the DB if needed (`sqlite3_exec()` without a callback function).
- Query the DB rows with `sqlite3_prepare_v2()`, `sqlite3_step()`, and `sqlite3_finalize()`.
- In the loop you search if the name is found.
- Close the DB (`sqlite3_close()`).

As reported in the comments, this is not a good idea. If you want to see if something exists, query if it exists:

```
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    char *zSql = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM PlayerInfo WHERE name=?)";
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, zSql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, search_name, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_step(stmt);
    name_match = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

In this specific case, probably the parametrized query is an overkill, but who knows where that `search_name` comes from...

**WARNING**: no effort to have decent error handling.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I'm sorry for not creating a minimally working example. I can handle the injection prevention and error handling but I was just having trouble with matching names to the database.